# Invalid ID when assigning lookup field ID in apex. System.StringException

Tags: apex, lookup, system-error

I have a custom object called **Orders** that has a lookup field with another custom object called **Product**. I am assigning the product ID from product with the ID column in orders. **Product**'s ID field is a text field and **Orders**' ID field is a lookup field with relationship to **Product**'s ID field.

When assigning the id using the code below

```
Order__c newORD = new Order__c();
newORD.Item_Code__c = sku.Item_Code__c;
```

Where `sku` is of type **Product** and `newORD` is of type **Order**, the error System.StringException invalid ID appears. There are no validation rules on the lookup field.

Comment: Why don't you just use `newORD.Item_Code__c = sku.Id;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you said I think you are trying to assign a product code to a lookup field, but you need to assign its Id instead.

You are trying to assign, for example, `'ABC-1023'` to a lookup field, but it is expecting a valid Id, like `'a1p230000000000AAA'`, which would be `sku.Id`.